# Did Merlin's father Balinor use magic to save Prince Arthur?

Tags: magic, merlin-bbc, merlin

In the last episode of *Merlin* ([fandom](https://merlin.fandom.com/wiki/The_Last_Dragonlord)), Balinor, The Last Dragonlord, saves Arthur with a medication, then chants something. He later tells Merlin that it is of '[The Old Religion](https://merlin.fandom.com/wiki/Magic_of_the_Old_Religion)'.

Why did Balinor's eyes not change the way Merlin's does when he uses magic? Was it actually not magic?

The change of eye colour seems to indicate a drawing of power. That was my understanding. Merlin had not yet mastered his magic, during the battle with Nimueh. And, from what I understand, Nimueh learnt magic, was not born with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert, so I might be wrong. I think that The Old Religion is more than just spels and magic. It's also about balance, connecting with nature and belief in the old gods. Balinor said, that it's an old prayer - I think he was telling the truth. Merlin got his magic from Balinor, and in all the episodes that i saw, his healing magic doesn't work. Assuming that Balinor's magic is of similar nature, healing spels wouldn't work for him eihter.
On a diffrent note - if you check Merlins battle with Nimueh you will notice, that nither his nor her eyes changed colour. They reflected light but that's all. So the lack of change in Balinor's eye colour might be a simillar mistake. Sorry for any grammar mistakes - english is not my native language...